# Como ejecutar cron con phantomjs?

Tags: php, cron, phantomjs

resulta que tengo un problema al correr un cron en centos con la librería phantomjs, cuando lo corro manual si funciona pero al ponerlo en modo de cron no corre, les agradezco si me ayudan a buscar una solucion.

El comando es el siguiente, no se si para un cron se tenga que ejecutar de otra manera...

phantomjs /var/www/html/reports/automatic_reports/resources/screenshot.js http://localhost/reports/automatic_reports/resources/history_day.php?type_map=heatMap@id_company=770@start_date=2020-09-14%2000:00:00@end_date=2020-09-14%2023:59:59 /var/www/html/reports/automatic_reports/resources/capturas_test/heatMapwm770.png

Comment: `type -P phantomjs` te tendría que dar la ruta completa para usar en cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depende del sistema que uses, si usas sistemas linux / unix, el comado para listar un cron suele ser crontab -l y para editarlo contab -e, para formatear la linea podrías usar algo como https://crontab-generator.org, recuerda que si el comando solo funciona desde una ubicación especifica, es posible que tengas que incluir toda la ruta al binario phantomjs, por ejemplo `/var/algo/phantomjs arg1 arg2` en lugar de `phantomjs arg1 arg2`

Comment: Gracias!! si sirvió incluyendo la ruta al binario phantomjs :D